# FullSimplify of equation that contains Log has no effect (and I think it should)

Tags: simplifying-expressions

The following equation,

```
f = 
  (P ((2 - ϵ) Log[1 - ϵ] + (2 + ϵ) Log[1 + ϵ])) / 
    ((-1 + ϵ) Log[1 - ϵ] - (1 + ϵ) Log[1 + ϵ])
```

when fully simplified as

```
FullSimplify[f, {x2 == 1 - ϵ, x1 ==  1 + ϵ}]
```

does not change it. Why does Mathematica ignore my request to substitute in `x1` and `x2`?

Answer (score 1):

The answer appears to be that x1 and x2 needs to be part of my original equation for my approach to work. A solution that works for me ([although see new post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/182352/rules-for-simplifying)), is the following:

```
FullSimplify[f /. {1 - ϵ ->  x1, 1 + ϵ ->  x2}]
```

Comment: It looks like you saw and applied the bad answer I deleted. The trouble with this solution is that not all the occurrences of `ϵ` are eliminated. A proper solution would give `(P((1 + x1) Log[x1] + (1 + x2) Log[x2]))/(-(x1 Log[x1] + x2 Log[x2]))`

Comment: @m_goldberg. Ah, yes. And I just posted a question about this.

Comment: And I just answered it.

Answer (score 0):

```
f /. {a_ - ϵ -> (a - 1 + x2),  a_ + ϵ -> a - 1 + x1} // TeXForm
```

> $\frac{P ((\text{x1}+1) \log (\text{x1})+(\text{x2}+1) \log
>    (\text{x2}))}{(\text{x1}-2) \log (\text{x2})-\text{x1} \log
>    (\text{x1})}$