# How can I find the rules I need to simplify my expression?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

In a previous [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/182347/fullsimplify-of-equation-that-contains-log-has-no-effect-and-i-think-it-should/182349#182349), I simplified the following equation

```
f = 
  (P ((2 - ϵ) Log[1 - ϵ] + (2 + ϵ) Log[1 + ϵ])) / 
    ((-1 + ϵ) Log[1 - ϵ] - (1 + ϵ) Log[1 + ϵ])
```

$\frac{P ((2-\epsilon ) \log (1-\epsilon )+(\epsilon +2) \log (\epsilon +1))}{(\epsilon -1) \log (1-\epsilon )-(\epsilon +1) \log (\epsilon +1)}$

using

```
FullSimplify[f /. {1 - ϵ ->  x1, 1 + ϵ ->  x2}]
```

and got

> ```
> (P (-(-2 + ϵ) Log[x1] + (2 + ϵ) Log[x2]))/((-1 + ϵ) Log[x1] - x2 Log[x2])
> ```

$\frac{P ((\epsilon +2) \log (\text{x2})-(\epsilon -2) \log (\text{x1}))}{(\epsilon -1) \log (\text{x1})-\text{x2} \log (\text{x2})}$

While that is certainly and improvement, it is easy to see that the solution can be processed some more

```
(P ((1 + 1 - ϵ) Log[x1] + (1 + 1 + ϵ) Log[x2]))/(-(1 - ϵ) Log[x1] - x2 Log[x2])
```

$\frac{P ((-\epsilon +1+1) \log (\text{x1})+(\epsilon +1+1) \log (\text{x2}))}{-(1-\epsilon ) \log (\text{x1})-\text{x2} \log (\text{x2})}$

to give

> ```
> (P ((1 + x1) Log[x1] + (1 + x2) Log[x2]))/(-(x1) Log[x1] - x2 Log[x2])
> ```

$\frac{P ((\text{x1}+1) \log (\text{x1})+(\text{x2}+1) \log (\text{x2}))}{-\text{x1} \log (\text{x1})-\text{x2} \log (\text{x2})}$

My question is, is there any way to get Mathematica to seek these further simplification? Perhaps, at least, by stating explicitly that when these opportunities present themselves, it should carry them out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given

```
f = 
   (P ((2 - ϵ) Log[1 - ϵ] + (2 + ϵ) Log[1 + ϵ])) / 
     ((-1 + ϵ) Log[1 - ϵ] - (1 + ϵ) Log[1 + ϵ]);
```

to see what rules will be needed it useful to  look at

```
FullForm[{(2 - ϵ), 1 - ϵ, (2 + ϵ), 1 + ϵ, -1 + ϵ}]
```

which gives

```
List[
  Plus[2, Times[-1, ϵ]], 
  Plus[1, Times[-1, ϵ]], 
  Plus[2, ϵ], 
  Plus[1, ϵ], 
  Plus[-1, ϵ]]
```

and from which the rules

```
rules =
  {Plus[2, Times[-1, ϵ]] -> 1 + x2,
   Plus[1, Times[-1, ϵ]] -> x2,
   Plus[2, ϵ] -> 1 + x1,
   Plus[1, ϵ] -> x1,
   Plus[-1, ϵ] -> -x2};
```

can be written. Applying the rules

```
g = f /. rules
```

gives

[image: result]

#### Update

The following is added to address concerns raised by the OP in a comment to this answer.

1. You can write the rules in standard form or convert the `List[...]` form to standard form using the context (right click) menu's **Convert To** submenu. That is

   ```
   rules = 
     {2 - ϵ -> 1 + x2, 1 - ϵ -> x2, 2 + ϵ -> 1 + x1, 1 + ϵ -> x1, -1 + ϵ -> -x2};
   ```

will work just fine because all input is internally converted to full form anyway. I didn't do the conversion because I found it easier to copy and paste from the `List[...]` expression than to do the conversion in the notebook.

2. I do the formatting you see here manually to improve the readability go the post. I also manually format my Mathematica notebooks.

Comment: Two questions: 1. While I am sure there are excellent reasons for FullForm, can I convert this language to the standard? 2. How do you make the list like this? On my system, the output prints on a single line and is much unclearer than yours.

Comment: @user120911. I answer your additional questions in an update I've made.

Answer (score 0):

```
rules  = {a_ - ϵ :> a - 1 + x2,  a_ + ϵ :> a - 1 + x1} ;
f /. rules
```

[image]

```
TeXForm @ %
```

> $$\Large\frac{P ((\text{x1}+1) \log (\text{x1})+(\text{x2}+1) \log (\text{x2}))}{(\text{x1}-2) \log (\text{x2})-\text{x1} \log
>    (\text{x1})}$$

Answer (score 0):

```
f = (P ((2 - ϵ) Log[1 - ϵ] + (2 + ϵ) Log[
         1 + ϵ]))/((-1 + ϵ) Log[
       1 - ϵ] - (1 + ϵ) Log[1 + ϵ]);

f2 = f /. {1 + ϵ -> x1, 1 - ϵ -> x2, ϵ -> x1 - 1} //
   Simplify

(* (P ((1 + x1) Log[x1] - (-3 + x1) Log[x2]))/(-x1 Log[x1] + (-2 + x1) Log[x2]) *)

f3 = f /. {1 + ϵ -> x1, 1 - ϵ -> x2, ϵ -> 1 - x2} //
   Simplify

(* (P ((-3 + x2) Log[x1] - (1 + x2) Log[x2]))/(x1 Log[x1] + x2 Log[x2]) *)
```

Verifying,

```
f == f2 == f3 /. {x1 -> 1 + ϵ, x2 -> 1 - ϵ} // Simplify

(* True *)
```

Checking the complexity of the expressions

```
LeafCount /@ {f, f2, f3}

(* {45, 30, 27} *)
```

So `f3` is the simplest of the three forms